# Following tutorial hacking with swift, coded exact same thing, but in the output console, my output is coming this "[ ]"

Tags: arrays, list, image, printing

when I tried to use this code to get the images, I'm not getting list list of images

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var pictures = [String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
        let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)
        
        for item in items {
            if item.hasPrefix("nssl"){
                //load pics
                pictures.append(item)
            }
        }
        print(pictures)
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pictures.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Picture", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = pictures[indexPath.row]
        return cell
        
    }
}
```